# How can I get these social sharers styled correctly?

Tags: css, facebook, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming

At the bottom of the single post I have 4 social sharers, one being Facebook. I have it set to show the faces of people who like. I don't need many to show up, just a few...As you can see if you take a [look at the post](http://noahsdad.com/nyc-buddy-walk-2012-central-park/) they look odd right now. I'm just getting my feet wet with css so I would really appreciate any help getting this looking right. I would post some css, but I'm not sure what to post when I view the source. Hopefully it's an easy fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply because you don't have enough space to fit every element.

This is not the best solution but it's certainly the quickest, just put this snippet in your CSS and it should work:

```
.dd_button {
    width: 85px;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I don't think I was being clear, sorry. I know there isn't enough room, what I was asking is how could I style it so it all fits and looks good?

Comment: I added that css to my child theme but it doesn't look like it changed anything?

Comment: Are you sure the CSS is actually loading? Did you try to clear the browser cache?

Comment: Hm.. if you're not logged in with facebook the text is much longer. You may want to just put facebook in the second line, just chagne that "width: 85px;" to "height: 30px;" and should work fine.

Comment: Hmmm.thanks for helping...I made the change..now take a look. Ha,ha.. Thoughts?

Comment: No worries! Hm.. I don't know if you planned this but I can see all the social buttons overlapping each other? I think you changed the width to 30px, try removing width and add height propert of 30px, that should look better!

Comment: Ha,ha. Nope, I didn't plan on that. That's what I was saying was messed up. But it looks much better now. Thanks so much for your help. You mentioned it wasn't the best way to clean it up. Do you have any other ideas how to style those sharers so they look nice? :-)

Comment: Just chiming in here- you have to realize that some of these share buttons are actually loaded as little itty bitty iFrames. As such, there is little you can do to alter their appearance in any significant way. The only thing you can do, as Adaz here has pointed out, is alter the width of the box that holds the button.

Comment: @chipcullen Thanks. I'm aware of that, but I also know there are lots of creative ways to use css to make them look good (the layout, placement, etc)